# C++ Error c2512: No default constructor avaliable

Tags: c++, constructor

I know that there are a lot of questions about this but I don't get it D: I'm sorry, I'm new at this and there's some stuff I still don't understand...  This is for a homework, where I need to set an alarm for the timer, suddenly this error appeared (it wasn't there when I was working at the school's computer) and I don't know how to fix it so please help me!
This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Display {
public:
    Display(int lim);
    void Increment();
    void SetValue(int val);
    int GetValue();
    void Show();
    int GetLimit();

private:
    int limit, value;
};

class Timer {
public:
    Timer();
    void Increment();
    void Set();
    void SetAlarm();
    void Show();
    void ShowAlarm();

private:
    Display hours, minutes, seconds, alarmH, alarmM, alarmS;
};

Display::Display(int lim)  {
    value=0;
    limit=lim;    }

void Display::Increment()  {
    value++;
    if (value==limit)
        value=0;   }

void Display::SetValue(int val)   {
    if (val<0)
        val=-val;
    value=(val%limit);   }

int Display::GetValue()  {
    return value;   }

void Display::Show()  {
    if (value<10)
        cout<<"0";
    cout<<value;  }

int Display::GetLimit() {
    return limit;  }

Timer::Timer():hours(24), minutes(60), seconds(60) {
}

void Timer::Increment()  {
    seconds.Increment();
    if(seconds.GetValue()==0) {
        minutes.Increment();
        if(minutes.GetValue()==0)
            hours.Increment();} }

void Timer::Show()  {
    hours.Show();
    cout<<':';
    minutes.Show();
    cout<<':';
    seconds.Show();  }

void Timer::ShowAlarm()  {
    alarmH.Show();
    cout<<':';
    alarmM.Show();
    cout<<':';
    alarmS.Show();  }

void Timer::Set()  {
    int setting;
    cout<<"Poner horas a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<hours.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    hours.SetValue(setting);
    cout<<"Poner minutos a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<minutes.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    minutes.SetValue(setting);
    cout<<"Poner segundos a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<seconds.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    seconds.SetValue(setting);    }

void Timer::SetAlarm()  {
    int setting;
    cout<<"Poner horas a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<hours.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    alarmH.SetValue(setting);
    cout<<"Poner minutos a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<minutes.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    alarmM.SetValue(setting);
    cout<<"Poner segundos a que valor?\n";
    cout<<"Ingresa un entero entre 0 y "; cout<<seconds.GetLimit()<<": ";
    cin>>setting;
    alarmS.SetValue(setting); }

void main()  {
    Timer t;
    cout<<"Aqui esta el valor incial del timer: ";
    t.Show();
    cout<<"\n\n";
    t.Set();
    cout<<"Aqui estan los nuevos valores: ";
    t.Show();
    cout<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Lo corremos por 10 segundos...\n";
    for (int i=0;i<=10;i++)  {
        t.Increment();
        t.Show();
        cout<<'\n';    }
}
```

Comment: Your error could not possibly be any clearer considering it should point you to the error line.

Comment: Hint: You have members of class `Display` but `Display` lacks a default constructor.

Comment: yes, it does, but that makes no sense... it points me to line 61 and that is: 
Timer::Timer():hours(24), minutes(60), seconds(60) {
}

But the error says that Display has no default constructor...

Comment: Also, `void main` is wrong; `main` always returns an `int`.  Not the bug here, but wrong for the language.

Comment: Because `Timer`'s parameterless constructor has `Display` members, which implicitly use the parameterless constructor.

Comment: Joe thanks, but I didn't wrotethat part of the code, that was the teacher s: and it worked ok before, she said that when you use a void you don't have to write the Return part, though we're still starting so maybe we don't see that yet.

Oh and that's the problem, I don't have any idea of how to make a default constructor, could you tell me how please?

Comment: I provided an answer -- however someone beat me to it so I'll delete it. Just know void main() is illegal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Timer class has Display objects as data members, and Timer's constructor does not explicitly construct all of them (AlarmH, AlarmM, AlarmS). The compiler therefore tries to use Display's default constructor to construct them, but there isn't one. This is because you've provided a (non-default) constructor for Display, so the compiler doesn't automatically generate a default constructor for you (it would do so if you hadn't provided any constructor at all for Display).

The solution: explicitly provide your own default constructor for Display.

Declaration:

```
class Display {
public:
    Display(); // Default constructor
    Display(int lim);
    void Increment();
    void SetValue(int val);
    int GetValue();
    void Show();
    int GetLimit();

private:
    int limit, value;
};
```

Definition:

```
Display::Display(){} // Default constructor

Display::Display(int lim)  {
    value=0;
    limit=lim;    }

// etc.
```

Comment: Thanks! It cleared it out, though it didn't completely fixed it on Visual, now it says:
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Display::Display(void)" (??0Display@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Timer::Timer(void)" (??0Timer@@QAE@XZ)  
 S:

Comment: @Eirikra My answer only had a declaration for Display(). I've edited it to show you how to provide the definition too.

Comment: ooooooh, haha didn't know I had to put that too, thank you! :)